# Ghost.exe + PXE

Tags: ghost, pxe-boot

I have created a boot disc for clients to connect to Ghost 11. Rather than use physical media to boot clients we have loaded the boot disc onto a PXE server which clients the download and boot. Ghost.exe executes and connects to the server but the only partition available is the 23 MB partition that the image was tftp'd to. I am currently looking through config.sys for hints but am looking for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Your config probably lacks the driver for the storage controller - if it is some AHCI thingy, you would need one for your DOS bootdisk (PXE is nothing but a virtual bootdisk transferred into the client's memory through TFTP).

You could also try to change the controller mode to "Compatibility" in BIOS Setup, if this alternative is available. This would expose the controller through the legacy interfaces usable with DOS and most other old operating systems out-of-the-box.

Comment: I failed to mention this earlier; the boot disc works (addresses and reads/writes to/from the hard drive) when booted from cdrom. Only when booted from PXE is the hard drive not accessible.